# How can I add html tags in Javascript: var quotes = new Array("tags html here")

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, quotes

Hello I try to add html tags in the "array" of my code, can you help me?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var quotes = new Array("exemple exemple","exemple...");
    var randno = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
    $('.quote').append(quotes[randno]);
    console.log(randno);
}
```

Comment: And you haven't specified any question.

Comment: question not clear at all. Are you wanting to pass php array to javascript?

Answer (score 0):

simple write the tags you want into the array (and use `'` for quotes in the tags)

```
....
var quotes = new Array("<li>bla</li>","<a href='http://www.google.com'>link</a>");
```

or

```
....
var quotes = new Array();
quotes.push("<li>asdf</li>");
```

Comment: HTML tags are not enhanced and appear in plain text

Comment: what type of element is your '.quote'?

Comment: var quotes = new Array("« L'amitié du chien est sans conteste plus vive et plus constante que celle de l'homme »(Montaigne)","Other text...");

Comment: not the array. i mean the element you append the value of the array ($('.quote'))

Comment: $('.quote').text(quotes[Math.floor ( Math.random() * quotes.length )]);

Comment: i am sorry, but did you not say you want to add HTML tags into the array?!? The code i gave you works.